# Calculation library

Tags: java, calculated-columns

I need to do some calculations like this (simplified):

```
            amount1     amount2     amount3     amount4     total
            5000        500         1000        350         6850

3.55%       177.5       17.75       35.5        12.43       243.18
1.00%       50          5           10          3.5         68.5

-           4772.5      477.25      954.5       334.07      6538.32

16.66%      ....
...
```

The calculations are pretty easy; But I'm not sure how I best implement this.
I don't only need to be able to fetch and show the total results from the calculations but also every sub calculation.
I can make a method for every sub calculation and group methods together in one for a total calculation. 
f.e.:

```
calcTotal1() {
    calcSub1() + calcSub2() + ... ;
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way to implement this.
It also should be a little library that can be used by different programs.

Comment: Good thing you ask. Money calculations with percentages are rather complex. You have to have overall rounding accuracy in both dimensions of your table, and that's not easy to achieve...

Comment: true, need to look into that :) I guess using BigDecimal is the way to go?

Comment: You *could* do the calculations themselves with float/double, as you round values up/down to the nearest cent. If you want to stay on the safe side, though, `BigDecimal` is a good idea too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, your requirement could be nicely met with an array of percentages to be calculated:

```
 public BigDecimal[] calculate(BigDecimal[] percentages, BigDecimal amount) {
     BigDecimal rolling = amount;
     BigDecimal[] result = new BigDecimal[percentages.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < percentages.length; i++) {
        // We use null as a marker for subtotals
        if (percentages[i] != null) {
           result[i] = amount.multiply(percentages[i]).divide(new BigDecimal("100"), MathContext.DECIMAL128);
           rolling = rolling.add(result[i]);
        } else {
           // Insert the subTotal
           result[i] = rolling;
        }
     }
```

Please note the use of `BigDecimal`s, while they do use a bit more memory, it will have a severe impact on the correctness of your figures.

With `null`s in the percentages[], you can specify rows where subtotals have to be printed out.

Answer (score 1):

The example is a table and tables are best processed with databases. If this is just a part of a larger program you can use an in memory database like SqlLite, HSql or any other relational database.

Define a table with different columns required by the computation with `create table` statement.

Then populate the table with data using `insert into` statement. Some parts of the calculation may be done in this phase, like entering values for percentages that should be calculated on every cell of an inserted row of data.

Finally retrieve the data doing the total computation using `select from` statement.

By using explicitly a database table your solution will be much more readable, intention will be better communicated and the overall solution will span over less lines of code.

Comment: While I agree with the idea of possibly delegating that work to a database, that's not explaining how to do the actual calculations with SQL...

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."
Chinese Proverb

Comment: OK. But how to do the calculation of percentages and sums thereof across various columns/rows in - for instance - HSQLDB?